# Why does Number.EPSILON act different on different operands?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Consider condition

```
(-1 - Number.EPSILON < -1) === (-2 - Number.EPSILON < -2)
```

This example is executed in Chrome console on my machine to `false` (?!), but I can't get why (left part is true, when right part is false). The whole condition also executes to `false` in Edge and Firefox, **but** to `true` in Internet Explorer (??!?).

[image: What happens on Chrome console]

Comment: Because `2 + Number.EPSILON === 2`, which is because of the nature of floating-point numbers.

Comment: probably floating point math

Comment: If you check at the `MDN`, there says that `Number.EPSILON`  is [not supported on Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON#Browser_compatibility). So probably, on **internet explorer** `Number.EPSILON` is evaluated to `undefined`.

Comment: @melpomene, thanks, but why `1 + Number.EPSILON !== 1` ?

Comment: Do you understand melpomene’s answer? If not, does the following help? Consider a decimal floating-point format with three digits. It could represent 1.23, 3.79, 32.1, 966., .722, and so on, but not 1.234, because that has four digits. For this format, `Number.EPSILON` is .01—it is the smallest step you can make from 1, from 1.00 to 1.01. But from 10.0, the next step is 10.1. We cannot go to 10.01. `Number.EPSILON` is scaled for 1. In binary floating-point, 2 is like 10; it has one more binary digit than 1 does. So it is too big to be changed by an amount as small as `Number.EPSILON`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating-point numbers are centered around zero. That is, they're densest around 0; the bigger your numbers get in magnitude, the fewer floating-point numbers exist in that region of the number line.

Bad ASCII approximation:

```
---------------------------------------(-1)-----(0)-----(1)------------------------------------------
 .        .     .    .    .  .  .  . . . .................. . . .  .  .  .    .    .    .        .
```

The upper line represents the real numbers; the dots below mark possible floating-point values. There are many possible floating-point values between -1 and 1, allowing for very fine-grained distinction. The further away you get from 0, the sparser the possible floating-point values become, which means bigger numbers are stored with less precision.

[`Number.EPSILON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON) is the distance between 1 and the next higher floating-point number. That means `1 + Number.EPSILON` exists as a floating-point value and can be represented exactly. The same applies to `-1 - Number.EPSILON`, which is the same value, but with a negative sign.

However, `2 + Number.EPSILON` does not exist. Because 1 is closer to 0 than 2 is, floating-point numbers are more dense around 1 than around 2. In particular, the difference between 2 and the next higher floating-point value is bigger than `Number.EPSILON` (in fact, I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out to be `2 * Number.EPSILON`). Because `2 + Number.EPSILON` cannot be represented exactly, it is rounded to the nearest floating-point number, which turns out to be 2 itself:

```js
console.log(2 + Number.EPSILON === 2);  // true
```

As for Internet Explorer: It [does not support `Number.EPSILON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON#Browser_compatibility), so

```
-1 - Number.EPSILON < -1
```

is evaluated as

```
-1 - undefined < -1
```

which is `Number.NaN < -1`, which (like all comparisons involving `NaN`) evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript number is double precision floating number (64 bit). Where bits 0-51 represents fraction and rest bits are for exponent.

If you try to convert `Number.EPSILON` to binary - You'll see that it is:

```
>  Number.EPSILON.toString(2)
'0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
```

The first bit is `0`, so if you add 1 - it becomes 1, and it still fits into fraction bits:

```
>  (1 + Number.EPSILON).toString(2)
'1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
//---- So -----
(1+Number.EPSILON) !== 1
```

But when you add `2` (binary `10`) it catches additional bit on the left - so the right (less significant) bit is cut - to fit into fraction bits.

```
2 + Number.EPSILON
10.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000|1  <- right bit dropped
                                                      ^
                                                      51 bit
//---- So -----
(2+Number.EPSILON) === 2
```